# Can't access JasperReports after deploying Grails WAR to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, jasper-reports

I have a Grails 2.4 application that uses JasperReports to produce PDF vouchers. I have everything working fine I run as dev environment on localhost.

I want to deploy to AWS on an Elastic Beanstalk instance but once I have uploaded the WAR and deployed it, everything works fine apart from JasperReport creation. When I click on the PDF icon if waits for some time and then give the error "An error has occurred" and no report is downloaded.

I have researched and found that the web-app/reports directory (this is where my jasper report files are) is not by default included in WAR creation so I have included the following in my BuildConfig.groovy and now the WAR contains the jasper report files correctly.

```
grails.war.copyToWebApp = { args ->
 fileset(dir:"web-app") {
     include(name: "js/**")
     include(name: "css/**")
     include(name: "WEB-INF/**")
     include(name: "reports/**")
     include(name: "images/**")
 }
}
```

After deploying again it still does not work and it seems that the app cannot access them.

Do I need to include any other files / directories in the WAR file I might be missing?

Is there a change in a config file I need to make to make this work - for example does deploying to a WAR change the directory structure in anyway that might effect a path in config file?

Just to add for clarity  - I have compile ":jasper:1.11.0" in my BuildConfig.groovy already.

*** UPDATE ***

I couldnt find an actual solution to this on Elasticbeanstalk but I have fixed the problem for me by changing to use an EC2 instance of Ubuntu and installing apache, tomcat, java etc myself and deloying there and I know have it working no problems.

Comment: any exceptions?  log entries?

Comment: my first time using aws so was having to look for where i find logs but have found now.There is one error that might be causing the problem "2015-04-11 01:05:17,323 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Arial Rounded MT Bold' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details."  - a missing font , So I will try embedding that font with ireports later and try again,

Comment: ive tried embedding a jar in ireports with the font in it but still not luck. So i tried to get ssh access to the EB instance but because there was no keypair assigned to it you cannot add it afterwards so I decided to resetup the entire AWS setup , on ubuntu instead of amazon linux and make sure I have ssh access, then redeploy so I can trouble shooting better and install any fonts through the console to see if that fixes things

Comment: Im still stuck on this and have run our of ideas now. Tried creating the report with the most basic SansSerif fault and just one basic field and still the same,It takes one minute then errors. Nothing in the logs to show why that I can see. Im not even sure if it is teh fonts issue that is causing it to crash but dont know where to look. Getting to the point where I might have to try a different hosting solution now. Wasting days on this